# Start virtual machine and log in

Tags: vmware, vmrun

I want to start a redhat linux virtual machine. I use the next command:

*vmrun **-gu myUser -gp myPass** start "C:\Users\myUser\Desktop\VirtualMachines\vmachine.vmx"*

VMware Player starts and then the operating system loads but user and password is required in the guest.

Is it not possible to authenticate directly?

What's wrong?

Best regards.